# Pine Script : The color of histogram can't be colored

Tags: pine-script, forex

i'm a pine script beginner coder

i wanna make an indicator for average candle length
all histogram bars will be black except that it's tale > 10% of (high-low) of the candle

> Default color is black
>
> green_upper_tale is the upper tale of the green candle
>
> red_upper_tale is the upper tale of the red candle
>
> green_lower_tale is the lower tale of the green candle
>
> red_lower_tale is the lower tale of the red candle
>
> actually_bar_length is the over all length of the candle

```
//@version=3
study("Candle Length")

len = input(20, minval=1, title="# of Bars to calculate average")
sum = 0.0
bar_color = black       // Default color

for i = 0.0 to len-1
    sum := sum + (high[i] - low[i])

green_upper_tale = 0                    // the upper tale of the green candle
red_upper_tale = 0                      // the upper tale of the red candle
green_lower_tale = 0                    // the lower tale of the green candle
red_lower_tale = 0                      // the lower tale of the red candle


multiplier = 1.0
multiplier := iff(close <= 10.0, 10000.0, multiplier)
multiplier := iff(close >= 10.0, 100.0, multiplier)
active_bar_length = (close-open)*multiplier
actually_bar_length = (high-low)        // the over all length of the candle


// for GREEN candles
if (close > open)
    green_upper_tale = high-close       // the upper tale of the green candle
    green_lower_tale = open-low         // the lower tale of the green candle

if (green_upper_tale > (actually_bar_length*0.1)) // if the green_upper_tale > (actually_bar_length/10) the candle bar will be blue
    bar_color := blue




// for RED candles
if (close < open)
    red_upper_tale = high-open          // the upper tale of the red candle
    red_lower_tale = close-low          // the lower tale of the red candle

if (red_lower_tale > (actually_bar_length*0.1)) // if the red_lower_tale > (actually_bar_length/10) the candle bar will be yellow
    bar_color := yellow



if (active_bar_length > 0)
    active_bar_length  :=  active_bar_length * 1


if (active_bar_length < 0)
    active_bar_length  :=  active_bar_length * -1


plot((sum/len)*multiplier)
plot(active_bar_length, color=bar_color, title="test1", style=histogram, linewidth=3)
```

the problem is histogram bars always black !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use the [variable assignment](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v3/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#variable-assignment) operator for green and red candles check here:

```
// for GREEN candles
if (close > open)
    green_upper_tale = high-close       // the upper tale of the green candle
    green_lower_tale = open-low         // the lower tale of the green candle

// for RED candles
if (close < open)
    red_upper_tale = high-open          // the upper tale of the red candle
    red_lower_tale = close-low          // the lower tale of the red candle
```

Just change those `=`s to `:=` and it will be fine.

Except, you should also change your `xxx_tale` variables to float type.

```
green_upper_tale = 0.0                    // the upper tale of the green candle
red_upper_tale = 0.0                      // the upper tale of the red candle
green_lower_tale = 0.0                    // the lower tale of the green candle
red_lower_tale = 0.0                      // the lower tale of the red candle
```

[image]